# Baking normals doesn't work and looks weird

Tags: uv, normal-map

Wanted to get into Blender but it's been frustration after frustration.

So I am trying to bake normal from high to low but it's just not working. I've followed everysinge tutorial and none of them work.

[image: High UV]
[image: Low UV]
[image: What it comes out as]

So the first image is high UV, then low UV and how it comes out.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Been going at this simple problem for about 2 weeks now and still can't figure it out. Lost lots of time where I could have been productive elsewhere.

Comment: This is also caged. Don't know the difference but when not caged the outcome is worse something like this https://i.gyazo.com/70630f189fc14cf770c670eef1ab5f47.png

Comment: Well, your UV maps don't match up. In order for the Normal detail to be in the same location on both models, the UV maps have to match. Now, a high poly model is going to have more geometry than a low-poly model, but as long as you follow the same unwrapping strategy for both models, it will work out.